# Table in GWT-Bootstrap

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap, uibinder, gwt-bootstrap

Trying to add a table to my GWT app with Bootstrap, using UIBinder. From what I understad there is some sort of table ported to GWT-Bootstrap but I don't know which one to use and how to use it (couldn't find any documentation either).

I want something like this, with Bootstrap style of course:

```
<b:CellTable>
    <<ROW>
        <<COLUMN>>
           Text blabla
        <</COLUMN>>
        <<COLUMN>>
           Text blabla
        <</COLUMN>>
    <</ROW>>            
</b:CellTable>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are mixing up some things.

`<b:CellTable>` is basically a normal GWT `CellTable` with bootstrap styles (it extends normal `CellTable` and injects a custom `Resource` for the styles).

Bootstrap and GWT-Bootstrap also have styles for normal HTML tables.
You can either use the `<b:Table>` widget or you can just define `<table>` and add the corresponding bootstrap classname.

So there are three choices:

- If you need the functionality of `CellWidgets` (rendering a lot of records, fast performance) and want to have it with bootstrap styling then use `<b:CellTable>`
- If you just need a bootstrap styled HTML table and also want to interact with it use the `<b:Table>` widget.
- If you just need a static bootstrap styled HTML table then just use `<table class="table table-striped">`